# How do I send data from angular.js to cakePhp controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cakephp

I'm using this html code to pass data to my angular Book `$scope`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in moduleData | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
    <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.Schedule.name}}</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.Schedule.reg_start_date}}</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.Schedule.reg_end_date}}</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.C[0].faculty_name}}</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.C[0].venue}}</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell"><button ng-click="Book(data.Schedule)" type="button">Book</button></td>
</tr>
```

This is the `js` code where I was sending data to `bookSchedule` controller.

```
 $scope.Book = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
    // Posting data to php file
        return $http.post('http://localhost/cakephp-2.8.2/Schedules/bookSchedule',data);

  };
```

in console i'm getting this data

```
Object {id: "1047", created: "2016-02-12 03:34:51", modified: "2016-04-08 11:01:07", reg_start_date: "2016-04-08", reg_end_date: "2016-04-29"…}
```

`CakePhp` code where the `bookSchedule` controller is defined.

```
public function bookSchedule(){
$schedule_id = $this->request->data;
debug($schedule_id);
$data = $this->Schedule->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$schedule_id),
    'fields' => array('id', 'created', 'modified', 'reg_type_id', 'module_id', 'name')));
    $this->set('data', $data);
    $this->render('/Elements/ajaxjson','ajax');
}
```

debug($schedule_id) result

```
/app/Controller/SchedulesController.php (line 41)
array()
[]
```

I want **$this->request->data** to get that data which i have sent from angular.js controller, but getting a null array.
Can any body tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Add here debug($schedule_id) output.

Comment: @Salines added the output

Comment: Can you access http://localhost/cakephp-2.8.2/Schedules/bookSchedule in your browser?

Comment: Yes i can access but the output is the same as debug($schedule_id) result.

Comment: look here how to send data with Angular http://tutsnare.com/post-form-data-using-angularjs/

Comment: getting the same result with this technique also.